# Java Akka websphere pub sub

Tags: java, akka, cluster-computing, netty, publish-subscribe

I have two sides of an app running under websphere,

1. one processing data and submitting it via mq
2. one receiving data via mq (message driven bean)

Both sides are joined in a cluster

```
first.log:INFO  16:02:33.174 [ClusterPacing-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] Cluster(akka://ClusterPacing) - Cluster Node [akka.tcp://ClusterPacing@serverone:2531] - Leader is moving node [akka.tcp://ClusterPacing@serverone:2531] to [Up]
first.log:INFO  16:02:38.123 [ClusterPacing-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] Cluster(akka://ClusterPacing) - Cluster Node [akka.tcp://ClusterPacing@serverone:2531] - Leader is moving node [akka.tcp://ClusterPacing@serverone:2532] to [Up]
```

I created a topic subscriber for topic 'ReportStatus'

```
public void onReceive(Object message) {

    log.info("Received message: " + message);

    if (message instanceof SubscribeAck)
        log.info("Subscribed to: " + ((SubscribeAck) message).subscribe().topic());
    else if (message instanceof Report) {
        BatchedItemExecutionReport report = (Report) message;
        log.info("Received report: " + report + " from "
                + getSender());
    } else {
        unhandled(message);
    }
}
```

successfully as seen from the log file (first.log)

```
INFO  16:02:31.665 [server.startup : 2] sample.app.App - created BatchPacer: Actor[akka://ClusterPacing/user/BatchPacer#-1219521740]
INFO  16:02:31.665 [ClusterPacing-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] listeners.pacing.BatchPacer - Subscribing to: ReportStatus
INFO  16:02:31.720 [ClusterPacing-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] listeners.pacing.BatchPacer - Received message:     SubscribeAck(Subscribe(omsReportStatus,None,Actor[akka://ClusterPacing/user/BatchPacer#-1219521740]))
INFO  16:02:31.721 [ClusterPacing-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] listeners.pacing.BatchPacer - Subscribed to: ReportStatus
```

And a publisher

```
public class ReportPublisher extends UntypedActor {
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReportPublisher.class);

private ActorRef mediator = null;

private ActorSystem actorSystem = null;

int jobCounter = 0;

public ReportPublisher (ActorSystem actorSystem) {
    this.actorSystem = actorSystem;
    mediator = DistributedPubSubExtension.get(actorSystem).mediator();
}

public static Props props(final ActorSystem actorSystem) {
    return Props.create(new Creator<ReportPublisher >() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public ReportPublisher create() throws Exception {
            return new ReportPublisher(actorSystem);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Object message) {
    log.info("message: " + message);
    if (message instanceof Report) {
        Report report = (Report) message;
        log.info("got: " + report);
        publish(report);
    } else {
        unhandled(message);
    }
}

void publish(Report report) {
    log.info("Sending: " + report);
    mediator.tell(new DistributedPubSubMediator.Publish(
            REPORT_STATUS_TOPIC, report), getSelf());
    log.info("Sent.");
}
}
```

when somewhere in the code I call

```
reportPublisher.tell(report,null);
```

the message get sent as seen in second.log

```
INFO  16:03:34.896 [ClusterPacing-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] oms.app.ReportPublisher - message: Report[Exception:null, ReportError:null, GatewayError:null, , id:15042002200380001]
INFO  16:03:34.896 [ClusterPacing-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] oms.app.ReportPublisher - got: Report[Exception:null, ReportError:null, GatewayError:null, , id:15042002200380001]
INFO  16:03:34.897 [ClusterPacing-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] oms.app.ReportPublisher - Sending: Report[Exception:null, ReportError:null, GatewayError:null, , id:15042002200380001]
INFO  16:03:34.897 [ClusterPacing-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] oms.app.ReportPublisher - Sent.
```

only it's never received on the topic subscriber...

Config file is as follows

```
akka {

    loglevel = "DEBUG"
    actor.debug.unhandled = on

    extensions = ["akka.contrib.pattern.DistributedPubSubExtension"]

    actor {
                    provider = "akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider"
    }

    remote {
            enabled-transports = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]
            netty.tcp {
                    hostname = serverone
                    port = 0
            }
    }

    cluster {
        seed-nodes= [
                    "akka.tcp://ClusterPacing@serverone:2531",
                    "akka.tcp://ClusterPacing@serverone:2532"
            ]
    }
}
```

Once again, this code runs in websphere as two separate apps joining the same (for now local) cluster

I wrote initially a standalone java app just to make sure the code works, and ... it works but NOT in Websphere

What am I doing wrong?!?

Thanks

Comment: I subscribed both actors (publisher and subscriber) to the cluster events and only AFTER they're [Up]  initialized the mediator and subscribe . Still at no avail. Messages are not received by the subscriber. :|

Comment: I subscribed both actors (publisher and subscriber) to the cluster events and only AFTER they're [Up]  initialized the mediator and subscribe . Still at no avail. Messages are not received by the subscriber. :|
Heartbeat messages are continuously exchanged between nodes in the cluster.
    Heartbeat to [akka.tcp://ClusterPacing@serverone:2531]
Heartbeat response from     [akka.tcp://ClusterPacing@serverone:2531]

akka 2.3.9
scala 2.11.5